# Building an AAR Library (debug vs release) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, aar

I am currently working on an android library, which I will try to use in later applications. I am using android studio as my main IDE, and I noticed that I can generate two types of .AAR files, one is Debug and one is release.
And I have Questions regarding them.

Q1: whats the difference between them (debug, release)?

Q2: is the release type more obfuscated than the debug type? If not, how do I secure my library such that it can't be reversed engineered(basically how do I hide my code so that it wont be easy to get access to it)?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between debug and release apks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864358/difference-between-debug-and-release-apks)

Comment: you can obfuscate AAR content, but that makes reverse engineering only more difficult, not impossible. If you don't want somebody else to see your code, don't give it to them. (but what's the point of creating a code, which will be not used?)