# React Native: generate release APK using npm command

Tags: android, react-native

I am using such command to generate an APK:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android
```

Is it possible to edit this command to generate release APK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native)

Comment: do you have android studio? if you have any experience with android studio there is a easy way to generate apk using that. if you had any experience tell me to share the guide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

`./gradlew assembleRelease` assembles all release builds (and generates release apk)

Your release build should be available under the following directory: **[projectRoot]/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/**

Comment: Is there any major differences between debug and release APK?

Comment: Yes, this answer describes them well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864358/difference-between-debug-and-release-apks

Answer (score 1):

```
  mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets
 && rm -rf android/app/build 
&& react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res 
&& cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleRelease && cd ../
```

I hope this will work for you…

Answer (score 1):

```
ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_bundleInArRelease=true npx react-native run-android --variant Release
```

then you will find the APK inside 
./android/app/build/apk/release/

I hope it helps you